# Azure Storage Explorer - Inadequate resource type access

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-sas

I am attempting to use the **Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer**, attaching with a SAS URI. But I always get the error:

> Inadequate resource type access. At least service-level ('s') access
> is required.

Here is my SAS URI with portions obfuscated:

```
https://ti<...>hare.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=co&sp=rwdl&se=2027-07-01T00:00:00Z&st=2019-07-01T00:00:00Z&sip=52.<...>.235&spr=https&sig=yD%2FRUD<...>U0%3D
```

And here is my connection string with portions obfuscated:

```
BlobEndpoint=https://tidi<...>are.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://tidi<...>hare.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://ti<...>are.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://tid<...>hare.table.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=co&sp=rwdl&se=2027-07-01T00:00:00Z&st=2019-07-01T00:00:00Z&sip=52.<...>.235&spr=https&sig=yD%2FRU<...>YU0%3D
```

It seems like the problem is with the construction of my URI/endpoints/connectionstring/etc, more than with permissions granted me on the server, due to the fact that when I click Next, the error displays instantaneously. I do not believe it even tried to reach out to the server.

What am I doing wrong? (As soon as I get this working, I'll be using the URI/etc to embed in my C# app for programmatic access.)

Comment: It appears that you are intending to use an account SAS, but the SAS does not have a SignedResourceTypes (srt) parameter, which is required (see documentation).https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas#constructing-the-account-sas-uri 

Where are you getting the SAS from? Or how are you generating the SAS?

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT The link in the question has "srt=co".  Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to connect is a service requirement the "SRT" part of the URI.
The URI you have has a SRT of "CO" container and object and needs the "S" part, you need to create a new sas key this can be generated in portal, azure cli or powershell.

In the portal is this part:
You have to enter to the storage acount and select what you need:

Allowed services (if you are looking for blob)
Blob

Allowed resource types

1. Service   (make sure this one is activated)
2. Container
3. Object

Allowed permissions (this to do everything)

1. Read
2. Write
3. Delete
4. List
5. Add
6. Create

Example where to look
[image]

If you need more info look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas?redirectedfrom=MSDN

If you like to create the SAS key in the CLI use this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli

If you like to create the SAS key in powershell use this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar issue trying to connect to the blob container using a Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL, and this worked for me:
**Instead of generating the SAS URL in Azure Portal, I used Azure Storage Explorer.**

1. Right click the container that you want to share -> "Get Shared Access Signature"
2. Select the Expiry time and permissions and click create

This URL should work when your client/user will try to connect to the container.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and managed to get this to work by hacking the URL and changing "srt=co" to "srt=sco".  It seems to need the "s".